# how to set value of ArrayList to multiple line textview

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I have a problem here. I have ArrayList which showing Google Places. I want to set the ArrayList        Value to Textview. But when the address of google place is long then textview not showing full address. I want to show full address in next line of textview.
Here is the sample code

```
private List<Address> getLocationInfo(String address) {

 List<Address> addrs = new ArrayList<Address>();
            String query = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +   address.replaceAll(" ","%20")
                    +"&components=country:"+appprefs.getString(Utils.CLIENT_COUNTRYCODE, "")+ "&sensor=false";
            Address addr = null;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(query);

            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

**xml code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textAutoComplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
android:padding="5dp" />
```

Comment: Patle check this link, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94048/android-reliver  This is chat room created by me, join.

Comment: Also accept the answer which you have got from other users, it will increase your points on stack overflow. as you need minimum 20 reputations to talk in the chat room created. Reply me once you read the msg.

Answer (score 0):

Use the singleLine attribute of TextView and set it to false.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

If the text you're putting in the TextView is short, it will not automatically expand to n number of lines. If you want the TextView to always have some n number of lines regardless of the length of the text in it, set the android:lines attribute:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINES_YOU_WANT"
    android:lines="NUMBER_OF_LINES_YOU_WANT" />
```